# HTTP PUT Request being blocked by the browser

Tags: javascript, html, http, form-submit, put

I have this html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contato</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a class="titulo" href="index.html">titulo &#128231;</a>
    </nav>

    <main>
        <form id="form">
            <label for="nome">Nome</label>
            <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
    
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu email">

            <label for="assunto">Assunto</label>
            <input type="text" id="assunto" name="assunto" placeholder="Digite o assunto">
    
            <label for="mensagem">Mensagem</label>
            <textarea id="mensagem" name="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem"></textarea>

            <label for="anexo">Anexo</label>
            <input type="file" id="anexo" name="anexo">
    
            <button type="submit" onclick="submitForm('/mail/send');">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </main>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this javascript code:

```
function submitForm(url) {
    const form = document.querySelector("#form");
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: new FormData(form)
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(response => {
        var main = document.querySelector("main");
        main.innerHTML = '';
        if(response == '') {
            main.innerHTML = '<h1>Mensagem enviada com sucesso!</h1>';
        } else {
            main.innerHTML = '<h1>Erro ao enviar mensagem! <small>'+response+'</small<</h1>';
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
```

Now, when I upload this files to the server, open the page in the browser, and try submit the form data, nothing happens, ans in the tab 'Network' from the 'Developer Tools' window, the PUT request is displayed as blocked.

[image]
[image]

The server has a servlet that accepts PUT requests (GET and POST request are being used already).

```
@WebServlet(name = "Send", urlPatterns = "/send")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1048576, maxRequestSize = 2097152)
public class Send extends HttpServlet {
...
    protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
...
    }
}
```

Anyone can give a hint of what's wrong here?

Comment: The status says it was *aborted* (because of the subsequent GET request caused by submitting a form and navigating to a new URL)